# Parse a json fromVAT eu

Tags: c#, json, parsing, c#-4.0

I have this json:

```
"rates": {
        "AT": {
            "country": "Austria",
            "standard_rate": 20.00,
            "reduced_rate": 10.00,
            "reduced_rate_alt": 13.00,
            "super_reduced_rate": false,
            "parking_rate": 12.00
        },
        "BE": {
     ...
```

And i try do map this json with this class but i have a problem becouse the way the json is strured a Tag is a Object. And i need to be a attributte

```
public class Rate{
public string Tag { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public double standard_rate { get; set; }
public double reduced_rate { get; set; }
public double reduced_rate_alt { get; set; }
public bool super_reduced_rate { get; set; }
public double parking_rate { get; set; }
}
```

how i map this into a sigle object? Thanks in advance

Comment: where is `Tag` in the JSON?

Comment: The Tag i wanto to be equals 'AT' or 'BE'

Comment: AT and BE act more like a key in a dictionary - look at the structure: theose are not with the rest of the data.  if you *must* have it be a property you';ll need to write your own converter, I think.

Comment: Yes The AT and BE is de id of dictionary. How i convert ? I can't change the output because is a web service external.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the (partial) JSON posted, the thing you want to refer to as the `Tag` is at a different level than the rest of the data.  Ignore the braces and look at the indentation.

It appears to be meant to be used as a Dictionary and easily deserializes that way.

```
{
"rates": {
    "AT": {
        "country": "Austria",
        "standard_rate": 20.00,
        "reduced_rate": 10.00,
        "reduced_rate_alt": 13.00,
        "super_reduced_rate": false,
        "parking_rate": 12.00
    },
    "BE": {
        "country": "Belguim",
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

The classes:

```
public class VRates
{
    public Dictionary<string, VRate> rates { get; set; }
}

public class VRate
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public float standard_rate { get; set; }
    public float reduced_rate { get; set; }
    public float reduced_rate_alt { get; set; }
    public bool super_reduced_rate { get; set; }
    public float parking_rate { get; set; }
}
```

The code to use it (using JSON.NET):

```
string jstr = ... json from where ever
VRates rates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VRates>(jstr);
```

Your "tags" will be the keys allowing easy look ups.  You can shed the outer class if you like:

```
var rates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VRates>(jstr).rates;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, VRate> kvp in rates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, country: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.country);
}
```

Output:

> key: AT, country: Austria
>   key: BE, country: Belguim

If you really want that code in the rates class, you could copy it to a new property then extract the dictionary values collection to a `List<VRate>` or write a converter to copy/move it.

Comment: Now i have a problem with bool and double, if a var is not a double return false in the json. i try to change the set method to :                bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out _reduced_rate);
                if (isDouble)
                    _reduced_rate = value;
                else
                    _reduced_rate = 0.0; and still get a error of parsing